# How can i load a function again once more content has been added via jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am using this zoom image script to load thumbs into larger images:
http://www.eyecon.ro/zoomimage/#implement

The trouble is i'm loading the gallery after the page is loaded using jquery load (code below):

```
//Remove tab info and add gallery
 $(".more").click(function () {
  var $gallery = $(this).closest('.tab').find('.gallery'),
  cat = $(this).attr('href').split('cat=')[1];

  if ($gallery.is(':empty')) {
   $gallery.load('/public/themes/lbd/js/imagegallery.php', {'cat': cat}, function(){
    $(this).fadeIn();
   });
  }

  $gallery.siblings().fadeOut(function(){
   $gallery.fadeIn();
  });  
  return false;
 });
```

The trouble is this script creates the gallery on the fly so the code below won't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.customGal').zoomimage();
    });
</script>
```

How can i work in the code above to run once the gallery is loaded the so function completes?

I have tried to add the $('a.customGal').zoomimage(); within .load but it doesn't work still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're trying to create a gallery out of `a.customGal`s, but your code isn't working because these anchors don't exist at page load. They're loaded from the `.click`.

If that is right, I believe this should work:

```
$gallery.load('/public/themes/lbd/js/imagegallery.php', {'cat': cat}, function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(function(){
        $('a.customGal').zoomimage(); 
    });
});
```

That will call your plugin after the HTML has been appended to your page *and* has finished animating.

Comment: I've added this code and it still doesn't want to work, you can see it on the link below.

Comment: I just checked your link. Looks like the path to your file `zoomimage.js` is throwing a 404. Check if the path is correct.

Comment: I love you!  No, really i do! A) what a knob i am!  I can't believe i made that mistake,  but i still think your code above i needed also to get it working, thanks!